# VLC playlists don't work after restarting ubuntu

Tags: vlc

I've saved playlists after assigning songs to them from the library. Loading the playlists and playing them works fine. But on restarting, after loading the playlists when I click on 'play', error message popes up telling 'the directory and file does not exist, see log for details.'

I've done as per your suggession.It's not working. Is the playlist extension xspf?

screenshot of the error dialog box follows. 
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Once you add files needed to your playlist then you can save it using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, or from the menu Media -> Save Playlist to File

[image]

Note you have always to load again the playslist once start VLC again, you can load it using Add file from playlist right click and load the playlist file.

use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This will open the playlist then right click Add File

Change file type from Media Files to ALL files so you can load the playlist files saved before

Comment: I've done as per your suggession, it's not working. Is it necessary that songs to the playlist are added from media library only?

Comment: How is that. I used it always, you seem to miss something, try again

Comment: problem persists...

Comment: You have to import the playlist each time you start VLC again

Comment: I've done that. Still the problem is there